# Jquery accordian ui is not working at all

Tags: jquery-ui

Jquery ui is definetely loaded as I have sortable working on the same page!

My html is as follows...

```
echo '<div id="accordian">
<h3><a href="#">Subscriber Options</a></h3>
<div><a id="changeLayout" href="">Change Main Layout</a></div>
<h3><a href="#">Account Layout</a></h3>
<div></div>
</div>';
```

My Jquery...

```
$(function() {
$("#accordian").accordian();
});
```

The jquery ui comes from google, and then my JS sheet after that, all my JS is wrapped in document.ready()

And my css for the accordian,

```
#accordian {width: 100%;}

#accordian h3 {padding: 5px 0; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; background: #333;}

#accordian div {padding: 10px 0; width: 100%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #f00;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this mistake so very, very often...

It's spelt `accordion` ;-)

The only other possible thing I can think is that you don't have the base CSS for the accordion loaded. I've set up [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vB7BY/) with jQuery 1.5.2, jQuery UI 1.8.9, the [base UI css from Google's CDN](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and your code and it works as expected.